# How to group multiple operations with using MongoDB aggregation

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, aggregation

Given the following Data:

```
> db.users.find({}, {name: 1, createdAt: 1, updatedAt: 1}).limit(5).pretty()
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5ec8f74f32973c7b7cb7cce9"),
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2020-05-23T10:13:35.012Z"),
    "updatedAt" : ISODate("2020-08-20T13:37:09.861Z"),
    "name" : "Patrick Jere"
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5ec8ef8a2b6e5f78fa20443c"),
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2020-05-23T09:40:26.089Z"),
    "updatedAt" : ISODate("2020-07-23T07:54:01.833Z"),
    "name" : "Austine Wiga"
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5ed5e1a3962a3960ad85a1a2"),
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2020-06-02T05:20:35.090Z"),
    "updatedAt" : ISODate("2020-07-29T14:02:52.295Z"),
    "name" : "Biasi Phiri"
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5ed629ec6d87382c608645d9"),
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2020-06-02T10:29:00.204Z"),
    "updatedAt" : ISODate("2020-06-02T10:29:00.204Z"),
    "name" : "Chisambwe Kalusa"
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5ed8d21f42bc8115f67465a8"),
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2020-06-04T10:51:11.546Z"),
    "updatedAt" : ISODate("2020-06-04T10:51:11.546Z"),
    "name" : "Wakun Moyo"
}
...
```

[Sample Data](https://gist.github.com/chibaye/92cbd7c1de29df8ce3cbede0f3643e1e)

I use the following query to return `new_users` by months:

```
db.users.aggregate([
    {
        $group: {
            _id: {$dateToString: {format: '%Y-%m', date: '$createdAt'}},
            new_users: {
                $sum: {$ifNull: [1, 0]}
            }
        }
    }
])
```

example result:

```
[
  {
    "_id": "2020-06",
    "new_users": 125
  },
  {
    "_id": "2020-07",
    "new_users": 147
  },
  {
    "_id": "2020-08",
    "new_users": 43
  },
  {
    "_id": "2020-05",
    "new_users": 4
  }
]
```

and this query returns `new_users`, `active_users` and `total users` for a specific month.

```
db.users.aggregate([
    {
        $group: {
            _id: null,
            new_users: {
                $sum: {
                    $cond: [{
                        $gte: ['$createdAt', ISODate('2020-08-01')]
                    }, 1, 0]
                }
             },
            active_users: {
                $sum: {
                    $cond: [{
                        $gt: ['$updatedAt', ISODate('2020-02-01')]
                    }, 1, 0]
                }
            },
            total_users: {
                $sum: {$ifNull: [1, 0]}
            }
        }
    }
])
```

How can I get the second query to return results by months just like in the first query?

expected results based on one month filter:

```
[
  { _id: '2020-09', new_users: 0, active_users: 69},
  { _id: '2020-08', new_users: 43, active_users: 219},
  { _id: '2020-07', new_users: 147, active_users: 276},
  { _id: '2020-06', new_users: 125, active_users: 129},
  { _id: '2020-05', new_users: 4, active_users: 4}
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try below aggregation.

Count new users followed by look up to count the active users for the time window for each year month.

```
db.users.aggregate([
{"$group":{
  "_id":{"$dateFromParts":{"year":{"$year":"$createdAt"},"month":{"$month":"$createdAt"}}},
  "new_users":{"$sum":1}
}},
{"$lookup":{
   "from":"users",
    "let":{"end_date":"$_id", "start_date":{"$dateFromParts":{"year":{"$year":"$_id"},"month":{"$subtract":[{"$month":"$_id"},1]}}}},
    "pipeline":[
      {"$match":{"$expr":
        {"$and":[{"$gte":[
          "$updatedAt",
          "$$start_date"
        ]}, {"$lt":[
          "$updatedAt",
          "$$end_date"
        ]}]}
      }},
      {"$count":"activeUserCount"}
    ],
  "as":"activeUsers"
}},
{"$project":{
  "year-month":{"$dateToString":{"format":"%Y-%m","date":"$_id"}}, 
  "new_users":1, 
  "active_users":{"$arrayElemAt":["$activeUsers.activeUserCount", 0]},
  "_id":0
}}])
```

Comment: what happen when month in _id is 1 and when subtract using `"$subtract": [ {"$month":"$_id"},1]`, will it manage by `$dateFromParts` or it fail?

Comment: What about something like this `{$subtract: [ _id, 2592000000 ]}`? The number is a month in milliseconds.

Comment: @francis - no need for months in milliseconds - date from parts  can handle overflow and it will adjust the year accordingly. You can verify on your data.

Comment: @turivishal - it will not fail and it will adjust to previous year in this case and month as dec.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the same, that you did in first query, group by `cteatedAt`, no need to use `$ifNull` operator in `total_users`,

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/1GCmX03mTqd)

---

Updated,

- use `$facet` group by month and count for both counts
- `$project` to concat both arrays using `$concatArrays`
- `$unwind` deconstruct array `root`
- `$group` by month and merge both month and count

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/X0FbhjW529p)

Comment: I've updated the question to include an example result. So `active_users` should be users where `updatedAt` is `$gt` the date in the `_id` minus 6 months. For example, if `_id` is `2020-07` then the `$cond` should be `{ $gt: ["$updatedAt", ISODate("2020-01-01")] }`.

Comment: `ISODate` should be dynamically generated based on the `_id`.

Comment: ok can you add expected result as per your find documents.

Comment: I've added a link to sample data and expected results based on 1 month filter since the data only goes back 5 months.

Comment: I don't fully understand how `$project` works but can't help to feel like it can help. In the first stage, we can grab all the dates, and in the second stage apply condition based on those dates.

Comment: can you look at this [playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/tKpBLbx2nt5)

Comment: Again there are hardcoded dates in the query. What I want is to return for each month users where the `updatedAt` field changed at least one in 6 months from that month date.

Comment: sorry, i am little confused, for the active_users, need users that are active from last 6 months, for example updatedAt date is "2020-01-01" and current date is 2020-09-14, it should not count in active_users because difference is 8 months and if updatedAt date is "2020-07-01" and current date is 2020-09-14, it should count in active_users because difference is 2 months am i right?

Comment: look at now for the active_users [playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/X0FbhjW529p), you need to provide milisseconds for 6 month.

Comment: Have a look at this [gist](https://gist.github.com/chibaye/83492699059786bab0d956e2447647bc). I'm getting an error `Can't convert from BSON type string to Date`.

Comment: Can `$dateFromParts` be replaced with `$dateFromString`?

Comment: the error from $project `$dateToString` it need to provide proper date.  dateFromParts and dateFromString both are different.